# Laravel 5.4 unable to set email from option

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.4

I am using global from option in config/mail.php as mentioned in the documentation to use the same from address for all of my emails being sent. This works as expected. However, when I attempt to explicitly set a from address within the build function of a Mailable class, the global address is still used. Is there something I could be missing, all of this seems to come straight from the documentation for 5.4. My Mailable class is as follows (there is definitely a value in the $this->email property as it is displayed when echoed):

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ContactMessage extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user_email;
    public $user_message;


    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user_email, $user_message)
    {
        $this->user_email = $user_email;
        $this->user_message = $user_message;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
//        echo '<pre>';
//        echo var_export($this->user_email, true);
//        echo '<br/><br/>';
//        echo var_export($this->message, true);
//        die;

        return $this->from($this->user_email)
                ->subject('Contact Message')
                ->view('mail.contactMessage');
    }

}
```

Comment: The code looks correct. Change `$this->from($this->email)` to a valid, hard-coded string -- like `$this->from('me@example.co')` -- and see if that works: I _suspect_ the `email` object variable may have special meaning to a `Mailable`. Also, include the full email headers of the resulting email.

Comment: Updated properties, prefixed with `user_` in case of conflict. Same results. Used `$this->from('someone@gmail.com')`, same results. Looking for way to export headers.

Comment: Something odd is going on. If I remove the default email address from the config/mail.php file, it is STILL being used. Investigating further.

Comment: I suspect you are using a MTA that doesn't allow from to be overwritten and it is configured, at the system level, with the default you want.

Comment: Sent to accounts on gmail and rackspace with the same results. The only way to change the from address is to change the actual email account that is sending the message via smtp. @bishop this would confirm your suspicion.

Comment: @bishop is more than likely correct. This would also be fairly standard configuration with most public MTA's. If you have access to mail logs, you could confirm this. You could also telnet the SMTP server yourself and try to send an email as a remote address.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. Thing is, setting the From header is a privileged operation in most MTA.

If you use `sendmail`, `postfix`, or other similars on a local machine you can usually set the From. However, when using an authenticated account at a third party, you usually cannot.

To change the From header with a third party, you need to either use an authenticated account that matches your From (eg with GMail), or configure the allowed From in your account (eg at AWS SES).